# Linux Driver for TRENDnet TEW-808UBM Micro AC1200 Wireless USB Adapter 20f4:808a

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

For the device
TRENDnet TEW-808UBM Micro AC1200 Wireless USB Adapter
20f4:808a,  see notes https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/issues/73

Please add support to this driver for the above device to Ubuntu, thank you.

Comment: EntropicEffect rtl8822bu driver https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu

Answer (score 0):

*The following solution was [originally posted as part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1265856/1) by the question's author:*

---

SOLVED:  RTL8822BU seems to be more appropriate for this micro USB, see line 250 at https://github.com/EntropicEffect/rtl8822bu/blob/master/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c.

I tested the EntropicEffect rtl8822bu driver using DKSM, and it WORKS. So, the chip is probably RTL8822BU, and not RTL8812BU as suggested by:
https://deviwiki.com/wiki/TRENDnet_TEW-808UBM
https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/TRENDnet_TEW-808UBM